# SQL Query for Attendance Matrix in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to generate one matrix attendance report based on employee entry_in and entry_out, both are datetime fields and group by date.

generally I would like to calculate like this

Please find the attachment

[image]

Please help me on this

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bit of a hack and slash, basically use `RECURSIVE CTE` to get the time groups, then `PIVOT` to generate the output you are after.

```
;WITH cte (groupNo, StartTime, EndTime)
AS (
    SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) as groupNo, CAST('06:00' AS TIME) AS StartTime, CAST('07:00' AS TIME) AS EndTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT groupNo + 1 AS groupNo, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, StartTime) AS StartTime, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, EndTime) AS EndTime
    FROM cte
    WHERE groupNo <= 13
)
SELECT emp_id, date_in, date_out, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT datetime_in) AS [NumberOfLogins], 
       SUM(ISNULL([1],0) + ISNULL([2],0) + ISNULL([3],0) + ISNULL([4],0) + ISNULL([5],0) + ISNULL([6],0) + ISNULL([7],0) + ISNULL([8],0) + ISNULL([9],0) + ISNULL([10],0) + ISNULL([11],0) + ISNULL([12],0) + ISNULL([13],0)) [Minutes], 
       SUM([1]) [6AM to 7AM], 
       SUM([2]) [7AM to 8AM], 
       SUM([3]) [8AM to 9AM], 
       SUM([4]) [9AM to 100AM], 
       SUM([5]) [10AM to 11AM], 
       SUM([6]) [11AM to 12PM], 
       SUM([7]) [12PM to 1PM], 
       SUM([8]) [1PM to 2PM], 
       SUM([9]) [2PM to 3PM], 
       SUM([10]) [3PM to 4PM], 
       SUM([11]) [4PM to 5PM], 
       SUM([12]) [5PM to 6PM], 
       SUM([13]) [6PM to 7PM]
FROM 
(
SELECT emp_id, date_in AS datetime_in, CAST(date_in AS DATE) AS date_in, CAST(date_out AS DATE) AS date_out, cte.groupNo, 
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (CASE WHEN CAST(t.date_in AS TIME) > cte.StartTime THEN CAST(t.date_in AS TIME) ELSE cte.StartTime END), 
                    (CASE WHEN cte.EndTime > CAST(t.date_out AS TIME) THEN CAST(t.date_out AS TIME) ELSE cte.EndTime END)) AS [minutes]
FROM scan_station_master t
INNER JOIN cte ON (cte.StartTime BETWEEN CAST(t.date_in as time) AND CAST(t.date_out AS TIME)) 
OR (cte.EndTime BETWEEN CAST(t.date_in AS TIME) AND CAST(t.date_out as time))
OR (CAST(t.date_in as time) >= cte.StartTime AND CAST(t.date_out as time) <= cte.EndTime)
) d
PIVOT
    (
      MAX([minutes])
      FOR groupNo in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13])
    ) piv
GROUP BY emp_id, date_in, date_out
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your brilliant effort. Just i replaced my table scan_station_master which my criteria fields are emp_id,date_in and date_out. But I'm getting below syntax error.                                                                   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: It's showing syntax error here(">") :                                                                                                        (IIF(CAST(t.date_in AS TIME)> cte.StartTime,

Comment: could you please edit your query which is support with my DB Engine. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I'm so sorry, when I tested with your query, It's working fine and getting result. but I screwed up with my real table. could you please edit with my real table and real fields. Table: (scan_station_master) Fields: (emp_id, date_in, date_out) send me the query again.

Comment: Wow! It's working. Thanks a lot for your great effort.

Answer (score 0):

review and try with other sample data.will discuss t'row

```
declare @t table(emp_id bigint,date_in datetime,date_out datetime)
insert into @t values
(392510,'2017/2/16 9:47','2017/2/16 11:31'),
(392510,'2017/2/17 11:26','2017/2/17 11:58')
,(392510,'2017/2/17 2:11 PM','2017/2/17 4:13 PM')
,(392510,'2017/2/18 15:30','2017/2/18 17:09')
,(392510,'2017/2/22 9:38 AM','2017/2/22 9:48 AM')
,(392510,'2017/2/22 11:55 AM','2017/2/22 12:10 PM')
,(392510,'2017/2/25 8:20 AM','2017/2/25 8:24 AM')
,(392510,'2017/2/26 13:37','2017/2/26 13:55')

;with CTE as
(

select t.emp_id
,t.date_in
,t.date_out
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('7:00 AM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('6:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('6:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('6:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[6 AM to 7 AM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('8:00 AM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('7:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('8:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('7:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('7:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[7 AM to 8 AM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('9:00 AM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('8:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('9:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('8:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('8:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[8 AM to 9 AM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('10:00 AM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('9:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('10:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('9:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('9:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[9 AM to 10 AM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('11:00 AM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('10:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('11:00 AM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('10:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('10:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[10 AM to 11 AM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('12:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('11:00 AM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('12:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('11:00 AM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('11:00 AM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[11 AM to 12 PM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('1:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('12:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('1:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('12:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('12:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[12 PM to 1 PM]   
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('2:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('1:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('2:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('1:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('1:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[1 PM to 2 PM]    
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('3:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('2:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('3:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('2:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('2:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[2 PM to 3 PM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('4:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('3:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('4:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('3:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('3:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[3 PM to 4 PM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('5:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('4:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('5:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('4:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('4:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[4 PM to 5 PM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('6:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('5:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('6:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('5:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('5:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[5 PM to 6 PM]
,case 
when  cast(date_in as time)>cast('7:00 PM' as time) and cast(date_in as time)>cast('6:00 PM' as time) then  null
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60 
then  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast(date_out as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time)) <60 
and datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time)) <0
then datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_in as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time))
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast(date_out as time) ,cast('7:00 PM' as time)) between 0 and 60
then datediff(MINUTE, cast('6:00 PM' as time),cast(date_out as time) )
when  datediff(MINUTE, cast('6:00 PM' as time) ,cast(date_out as time))>=60 
then 60
else
null
end 
[6 PM to 7 PM]
From @t t
)
select emp_id,min(date_in)date_in,max(date_out)date_out
,count(*)[Number of Login]
,sum([6 AM to 7 AM])[6 AM to 7 AM]
,sum([7 AM to 8 AM])[7 AM to 8 AM]
,sum([8 AM to 9 AM])[8 AM to 9 AM]
,sum([9 AM to 10 AM])[9 AM to 10 AM]
,sum([10 AM to 11 AM])[10 AM to 11 AM]
,sum([10 AM to 11 AM])[10 AM to 11 AM]
,sum([11 AM to 12 PM])[11 AM to 12 PM]
,sum([12 PM to 1 PM]  )[12 PM to 1 PM]  
,sum([1 PM to 2 PM])[1 PM to 2 PM]
,sum([2 PM to 3 PM])[2 PM to 3 PM]
,sum([3 PM to 4 PM])[3 PM to 4 PM]
,sum([4 PM to 5 PM])[4 PM to 5 PM]
,sum([5 PM to 6 PM])[5 PM to 6 PM]
,sum([6 PM to 7 PM])[6 PM to 7 PM]
from CTE t
group by t.emp_id,cast(date_in as date)
```

Comment: It's great query. Thanks for your help. But i'm struggling with same query run with real table. result shows null. my table is (scan_station_master) and  Data fields are (emp_id,date_in,date_out).

Comment: this version also working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.